# Firebase equivalente a Sum() SQL

Tags: javascript, sql, reactjs, firebase

Hola necesito saber si hay alguna funcion en Firebase donde pueda sumar los valores de cierta columna. Similar al uso de Sum() en SQL
Gracias

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Firebase es No-SQL, por tanto, no debes pensarlo como SQL o podrías meterte en un gravísimo problema. Imagina que recorres miles o millones de documentos o colecciones para sumarlos, Firebase computa la lectura de cada uno de esos elementos ... Es así como más de uno se ha llevado un gran susto en la facturación. Si quieres usar funciones de agregación (`SUM` y otras) debes programar código **para mantener la agregación en el documento** o usar Cloud Functions. [Ver aquí](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation#java) para más detalles.

Comment: Para que te hagas una idea del susto que te puedes llevar en un entorno Firebase mal diseñado, [aquí tienes un ejemplo](https://www.dottedsquirrel.com/30k-firebase/). La aplicación facturó 30,000 dólares en 72 horas, el problema era un error en el código que leía cientos o miles de documentos. Varios miles de usuarios y un código mal programado te puede dar un gran susto en Firebase, así que debes hilar fino y diseñar teniendo en cuenta que Firebase es No-SQL.

Comment: Sumo a lo que dice A. Cedano. En Firestore no hay columnas, sino documentos.

Comment: Entiendo, gracias por la respuesta. Estuve leyendo un poco lo que me pasaron. De todas maneras yo traigo documentos y los recorro con map para mostrarlos. Ahi mismo donde lo rercorro podria sumar los valores en una variable para despues mostrar el total que necesito? Es una buena idea?